# Accustom vs accustomed? Which is proper usage here?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

I'm using accustom in a sentence like so:

```
Users are already familiar with YouTube and are accustom to its expansive music catalog.
```

I'm wondering if this is an incorrect use of the word accustom. Should it be accustomed? I'm thinking accustomed is incorrect because it is present tense and not past tense, but maybe this is an exception to the language.

Comment: *"Should it be accustomed?"* -- yes. :)

Comment: Okie dokie. Weird. Why is there an ed at the end of a word being used in present tense? Just a one-off?

Comment: It is "are" that is in present tense. The word "accustomed" is either a past-participle verb or a past-participle adjective--in both cases, it has the "-ed" on it.

Comment: I am accustom to it. I am use to it. I am move by it. I am embarrass by it. I am sadden by it. I am bless. I am perplex and bewilder you think this is how we should be talking. And I am surprise that you can't tell a [tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_tense) from a [participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle). Her Majesty is not amuse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Accustomed to* would be correct here. It looks like a verbal expression, but it is really an adjective derived from the past tense of a verb (compare with *beat(en)-up* or *under-informed*). For instance, you could as easily say *conversant with* or *acquainted with* in this situation.

Incidentally, I think *extensive* would be a better fit than *expansive* here. The latter usually describes people's behaviour rather than objects.

Comment: *"but it is really an adjective derived from the past tense of a verb"* -- Er, no.